# redirect to URL via PHP

Tags: php

I have a form at index.php that takes in user input, it the includes and sends the user input to another php file for processing.

Here is the code of index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    include_once "form.php";
    exit(0);
}
?>
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
         <input type="text" name="q" />
    </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When one submits the form it goes to `http://mysite.com/?q=textUserEntered` (if just the domain was visited before) or `http://mysite.com/index.php?q=textUserEntered` (if index.php is visited before)

How can I get it to go to `http://mysite.com/form?q=textUserEntered` or `http://mysite.com/index.php/form?q=textUserEntered` while still passing the form data to form.php

I tried this in the beginning index.php and form.php, it navigates to the URL but doesn't pass the data to form.php and instead goes to a 404 error page.

```
if(!empty($_GET['q']))
{
    header("Location: form?q=".rawurlencode($_GET['q']));
    exit;
}
```

**Update:**

I can't use the action attribute because adding form.php to the value of the action attribute would make the URL `http://mysite.com/form.php?q=userEnteredText` not `http://mysite.com/form?q=userEnteredText`

Comment: is the redirect inside form.php?

Comment: @MatthewScragg Right now it is neither. But it doesn't matter if it is index.php or form.php, it only redirects on form submission and both times it goes to the 404 error page.

Comment: **Never Ever Duplicate Your Own Questions** - You only loose potential friends and get downvotes. Instead (at least) try to understand why you get no answers and improve your existing question by editing it: [redirect to different URL with .htacess or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16630176/367456)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CURL to post your data to form.php file and then you can redirect form.php to display form submission message.

**How to post using CURL:**

```
if(!empty($_GET['q']))
{
    $output_url = "http://www.yoursite.com/form.php";

    $data  = "q=$_GET['q']";

    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init ($output_url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $process_result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();



if ($process_result != '') {
    header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/form");
    exit;
}
}
```

**Also, write mod_rewrite code in .htaccess to redirect to form.php page using keyword 'form'.**

If you want to show 'q=userEnteredText' in url, you can use the below mentioned code.

```
header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/form?$data");
```

Comment: this still redirects to form.php, I need it to redirect to `http://mysite.com/form?q=userEnteredText` ? and then still post the data to form.php as if it was going for 'http://mysite.com/form.php?q=userEnteredText'

Comment: Do you really need to display "q=userEnteredText" in url? Also, i have edited my code.

Comment: yes, I do. userEnteredText is replaced by whatever the user types into the form. For example if the user enters chicken and submits it, right now it goes to `http://mysite.com/form.php?q=chicken`, but I want it o go to `http://mysite.com/form?q=chicken` while still passing the text entered, chicken, to form.php. Does your code do that?

Comment: I don't want it to be exactly ?q=userEnteredText, but userEnteredText be replaced with whatever the user types in the text-input field and submits.

Comment: Yes, it does. Check the code. I have modified it.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't see that latest edit. Where should I put this code? In form.php or in index.php?

Comment: I'm getting an HTTP 500 error when I put it in index.php, should it be in form.php ?

Comment: It should be in index.php. Also, define the action of form and wtite mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess.

Comment: Hope you found the answer useful. If so, you may accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the `.php` in the filename...

```
if(!empty($_GET['q']))
{
    header("Location: form.php?q=".rawurlencode($_GET['q']));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: But I don't want the url to look like `http://mysite.com/form.php?q=userEnteredText`. I want it to look like `http://mysite.com/form?q=userEnteredText` and still send the data to form.php.

Comment: That's a different thing from what you've asked about. Google "_mod_rewrite_" for Apache for a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: You can also use .htaccess for rewriting URLS.

Comment: @DiegoAgulló that is not a different thing than what I asked about. The same thing is said in like 7-9 in my question. Ignore the code blocks when counting the lines.

Comment: @blunderboy I don't use apache. so I can't use .htacess. There has to be a way without .htacess